# Word 365 hyperlinks open in wrong program or don't open

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, office365, hyperlink, microsoft-word-365

I have some Word files with hyperlinks to local .html, .pdf, .txt, .jpg, etc. files. On some machines, when I ctrl-click on the links to .html or .pdf files, Word tries to open them with another program than what is configured in Settings > Default Apps.

On other machines, some hyperlinks don't open at all, and there is an error saying "**no program is registered to open this file**".

On others, the error is "**You'll need a new app to open this about link**".

This happens on 3 Windows 10 machines, but not on two others where I have tested it.

For example, after a fresh install of Microsoft 365, Word tried to open local .html files in Internet Explorer. This was despite the fact that the Win10 Default Apps settings were set to Edge or Firefox for both .html files and for the default browser.

The settings work as expected when double-clicking a file in Windows. But Word 365 tried to use Internet Explorer 11 anyway. (And failed, showing just an "about:blank" page.)

Uninstalling Internet Explorer doesn't help. After re-installing Microsoft 365 again on one machine, it started working for .html files. But on another one where I get "You'll need a new app ...", the re-install made no difference.

For .PDFs, while it works on some machines, another always tries to use Acrobat instead. And fails: it opens the file in Acrobat, and immediately closes it (or maybe Acrobat quits immediately?). This is regardless of the settings for .pdf files in Default Apps.

So my questions are :

- where does Word lookup which program to use to open various file types?
- How can I remove any setting it has so that it uses the system's defaults?

There is also [this post on a forum](https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/48973-youll-need-new-app-open-about-link.html) describing the same problem with .jpg files.

Comment: Word looks to the file associations set in Windows. This depends on the settings on each computer. What is the default program to open that type of file on that machine?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: No, it does not look "to the file associations set in Windows"! At least not always or not only. That is the problem. The file associations are as I want, and the files open in the correct program when double-clicked in Windows etc.(eg. Firefox or Edge for .html files). It's only Word 365 which tries to use something else for hyperlinks and fails.

Comment: Similar question from May: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/hyperlinks-not-working-in-word-office-2016-windows/25c1cfc5-bb1f-4864-8061-00471ce099f1

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: YES! You could make this the answer, using the given officec2rclient.exe command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a bug. Introduced with Version 2204.

**Workaround** at [Microsoft Office Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/hyperlinks-not-working-in-word-office-2016-windows/25c1cfc5-bb1f-4864-8061-00471ce099f1)

> tested several recent Office update releases and I think I isolated
> the culprit that broke your Word doc links.
>
> For the **April 20 Version 2203 (Build 15028.20228)**, the test docs with
> JPG and PNG links work as expected when I click on the hyperlink. Note
> the first time I tried the JPG link, there appeared a security warning
> about dangerous file formats which you can ignore. Standard Microsoft
> procedure for JPGs.
>
> For the subsequent release of **April 26 Version 2204 (Build
> 15128.20178)**, the test docs with JPG and PNG links did not work and produced this error message when I click on the hyperlink: "No Program
> is registered to open this file." I checked my file associations in
> Windows settings and confirmed this is incorrect; my JPG and PNG file
> associations are still the same as ever.
>
> To rollback to the last working version, I modified LiranLustig's
> suggestion with the version number. You can use this command line
> (following LiranLustig's instructions):
>
> `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.15028.20228`
>
> After a successful install is achieved, open Word again, go to
> File\Account, and make sure to Disable Updates so you don't receive
> the rogue update. No telling how long the wait for an update with the
> bug fix but there's little downside to sticking with the April 20
> Version for a while.
>
> Note that I have tested this only on Windows 11 and Office 365. It is
> expected to work on Windows 10 and Office 2016 but no guarantees. As
> LiranLustig notes, this is not a system restore so it is relatively
> low impact and should not affect other operations or programs.
>
> So to recap, it appears the **April 26 Version 2204 (Build 15128.20178)**
> update introduced this bug.

Expect that this will be fixed,again, eventually.

Here is a [Microsoft Support page on reverting to a previous update version](https://support.microsoft.com/2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841).

Answer (score 1):

Since I had to apply this fix on several machines, I made a script to

- Disable automatic updates of Office 365
- Install the last version without this bug

In case it's useful for others, here it is:

```dos
@echo off

SET WantedVersion=16.0.15028.20228

REM Check we are running as Admin
openfiles 1>nul 2>nul
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    ECHO *** ERROR this must be Run As Administrator... ***
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B 1
)

echo Disabling Office 365 automatic updates
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration /v UpdatesEnabled /t REG_SZ /d False /f

echo Current version:
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration /v VersionToReport

echo Installing version %WantedVersion%
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=%WantedVersion%

PAUSE
```